# Alterar senha Aluno

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

No ambiente do aluno, o mesmo deverá alterar sua senha.

Criei o código abaixo mas não consigo resultados no banco. Alguém nota algo errado?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AlterarSenha(CONSUL_CA_Aluno aluno)
{
    string cpf = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    var bdAluno = CONSUL_CA_AlunoAplicacaoConstrutor.CONSUL_CA_AlunoAplicacaoEF();
    var alunoNovaSenha = bdAluno.ListarTodos().Where(x => x.Cpf == cpf).First();

    ViewData["aluno"] = aluno;
    ViewBag.Senha = aluno.Senha;
    bdAluno.Salvar(alunoNovaSenha);

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Acho que a primeira linha pode ser reduzida para `string cpf = Page.User.Identity.Name` (ou apenas `User.Identity.Name`... estou meio enferrujado).

Comment: Outra coisa... Se a consulta não traz resultados, existe uma possibilidade de que o retrno de `CONSUL_CA_AlunoAplicacaoEF`, ou do metodo `ListarTodos`, esteja vazio. Precisaríamos ver o código desses métodos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que você está tentando salvar `alunoNovaSenha` sem alterar a senha dele.

Considerando que a senha correta esteja em `aluno`, o código abaixo deve resolver o problema:

```
alunoNovaSenha.Senha = aluno.Senha;
bdAluno.Salvar(alunoNovaSenha);
```